# Total electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, reflection

Given a plane wave with the electric field component $$ \tilde{E}_{in} = E_0(-\hat{x} \cos \theta + \hat{z}\sin \theta)\exp [ i \frac{\omega}{c}(x \sin \theta + z \cos \theta) - i \omega t]$$

I've calculated the reflection on a metallic plane and it yielded

$$ \tilde{E}_{ref} = E_0(\hat{x} \cos \theta + \hat{z}\sin \theta)\exp [ i \frac{\omega}{c}(x \sin \theta - z \cos \theta) - i \omega t]. $$

I want to calculate the total complex electric field; i.e $ \tilde{E} = \tilde{E}_{in} + \tilde{E}_{ref} $.

The answer reads "With Eulers formulas we obtain $$ \tilde{E} = 2E_0 \exp[i \frac{\omega}{c} x \sin \theta - i \omega t](-i\hat{x} \cos \theta \sin (\frac{\omega}{c}z cos \theta) + \hat{z} \sin \theta \cos( \frac{\omega}{c} z \cos \theta))"$$

Q: Is there any smart way to conclude this?

Seems like a lot of work to obtain it through $ e^{i\omega t} = \cos \omega t + i \sin \omega t $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the most intelligent way to conclude this, but it does not require repeated use of $\exp(i\theta) = \cos\theta + i\sin\theta$. Recall that,
\begin{equation}
\cos\theta = \frac{e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta}}{2}
\quad
\text{and}
\quad
\sin\theta = \frac{e^{i\theta} - e^{-i\theta}}{2i}
.
\end{equation}

Therefore, adding the two electric field contributions
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\tilde{E} &= 
E_0\exp\left[i\frac{\omega}{c}(x\sin\theta) - i\omega t\right]
\left[
\left(-e^{\frac{i\omega}{c}z\cos\theta} + e^{-\frac{i\omega}{c}z\cos\theta}\right)\cos\theta\ \hat{x}
+
\left(e^{\frac{i\omega}{c}z\cos\theta} + e^{-\frac{i\omega}{c}z\cos\theta}\right)\sin\theta\ \hat{z}
\right]\\[0.25cm]
&=
2E_0\exp\left[i\frac{\omega}{c}(x\sin\theta) - i\omega t\right]
\left[
-\frac{i}{2i}\left(e^{\frac{i\omega}{c}z\cos\theta} - e^{-\frac{i\omega}{c}z\cos\theta}\right)z\cos\theta\ \hat{x}
+
\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{\frac{i\omega}{c}z\cos\theta} + e^{-\frac{i\omega}{c}z\cos\theta}\right)\sin\theta\ \hat{z}
\right]\\[0.25cm]
&=
2E_0\exp\left[i\frac{\omega}{c}(x\sin\theta) - i\omega t\right]
\left[
-i\sin\left(\frac{\omega}{c}z\cos\theta\right)\cos\theta\ \hat{x}
+
\cos\left(\frac{\omega}{c}z\cos\theta\right)\sin\theta\ \hat{z}
\right]
\end{split}
\end{equation}
which is the expected result. Hope this helps!